# Is it fine to use other prepositions other than "in" for months?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, time

In the following sentence (from [Duolingo French course](https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/28208314)):

> It is windy, **in** early April.

This is the correct answer and I wrote the following:

> It is windy, **at** early April.

I found this got rejected. But while I already know *in* is the correct preposition, I now wonder if it is grammatically correct, or not but used often, to use other prepositions such as *at* or *on* to refer to months.

Answer (score 1):

We use the preposition **in** when talking about an extended period of time... "in November", "in 1985".

We use the preposition **at** when we are talking about an exact time. "at 5pm", "at the beginning of the month". It can also be used for some religious holidays "at Christmas", "at Easter" but these are considered to be relatively short periods. We would say "in lent" rather than "at lent" because Lent is 40 days. In the same way, it would not be ok to say "at Ramadan", as Ramadan goes on for a lunar month- you would say "in Ramadan".